# How can I match the outer bracket with grep

Tags: grep, square-bracket

I want to extract all the lines from the file which is in the form of

```
T[0-9]-[0-9][.*
```

eg:

```
T1-3[1: 139343400 -- 81586290 --> 220929690]
```

I tried with `grep T[0-9]-[0-9]\\[.*` but I'm getting the following output.

> grep: Unmatched [ or [^

any suggestions/comments regarding extracting the above type of line would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is working fine to me in `grep (GNU grep) 2.18`. However, what if you try with just one backslash: `grep "T[0-9]-[0-9]\[.*"`

Comment: One backslash *and quoting* should work correctly.  Two backslashes means that you're looking for a literal backslash followed by a character set that you never finish defining.  Single backslash + open bracket = a literal open bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you tried

```
grep T[0-9]-[0-9]\\[.*
```

That should be fine.  But if you do

```
grep T[0-9]-[0-9]\[.*
```

then you'll get the "Unmatched [" because the "[" is converted by the shell to just "[".

You can also do

```
grep 'T[0-9]-[0-9]\[.*'
```

Comment: Thanks Andy.
Initially I was trying with only one backslash. I tried with double backslash and it worked.